# IMAP to Office 365 migration error

Tags: dovecot, microsoft-office-365, imap, exchange-migration

I am migrating mailboxes from an on-premise IMAP server to Office 365.  Most of the accounts are migrating fine, but I'm hitting the following error on a handful of accounts.

```
Error: MigrationMRSPermanentException: Error: Uid value is out 
  of range of allowed values. --> 0 Parameter name: lowBound
```

This *sounds* like an IMAP error to me, but it's not giving me much to go on.  Zero results on Google for this specific error message.

For the migration I'm using PowerShell, i.e.:

```
New-MigrationBatch -BadItemLimit 99 -Name pilot -LargeItemLimit 99 `
-CSVData ([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("migratelist.csv" )) -AutoStart `
-SourceEndpoint imap.example.org
```

with the CSV file containing the user list, e.g.

```
EmailAddress,UserName,Password
user@example.org,user*masteruser,masterpw
```

The IMAP server is Dovecot 2.2.33.2, with a Maildir back end, running on CentOS 7.  Dovecot has a master user configured to access the needed email accounts.  I have turned up debugging in Dovecot, and enabled rawlogs.  So far I haven't been able to identify what's causing the error.  Perhaps a corrupted message, but how to find it among thousands?  Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you try on one of the account that does not work and migrate from the user outlook directly ? aka a copy from his outlook to his 0365. You might get a better error message to look for a solution

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Well interestingly I was able to do the copy in Outlook without encountering any errors at all.  So at least I have a workaround.  Glad I have <100 to migrate and not thousands!

Comment: For what it's worth I updated my IMAP server to Dovecot 2.3.3-2 (latest) and now at least one of the problematic mailboxes is migrating properly.  Wish I had a more conclusive explanation of what was going on, but I'll take it.